# Git bash can't access home directory on fresh machine

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssh

I have just got my new laptop (Windows 7) and wanted to clone first repository. I'm using ssh connection and private key. To my surprise, git bash can't see my home directory to work with .ssh default directory:

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:<blablabla>
Cloning into 'XXX'...
Could not create directory '/u//.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (104.192.143.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/u/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

Instead of standard `/C/Users/my_name` i see `/u` in the paths - where did that come from? Looks like outside of Git Bash everything works ok, I also checked %USERPROFILE% env variable and it is set correctly.

**putting more details to clarify some questions**

1. I'm not using Cygwin. I only installed Git-2.10.1-64, entered empty directory `C:\Workspace`, right clicked and chose `Git Bash Here`.
2. `$HOME` directory is set to `/u/` - so I'm guessing this is the root of the problem. Should I forcefully change this variable in some of Git Bash's initial scripts?
3. Current directory is `C:\Workspace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `HOME` environment variable in Windows which points to my home directory - Git Bash can resolve it correctly now. I'm not sure whether it's best solution or some kind of workaround, though.